# Topological Insulators with Multiple Band Gaps

Tags: topological-insulators

Assume we have a $\mathbb{Z}$-topological insulator, i.e. a Chern insulator. Let its band structure have three bands with two gaps between them. Is it possible to have Chern numbers $C_1=1$, $C_2=-2$ and $C_3=1$?

If so, does this mean that there are edge states connecting both gaps? Further, would $C_1=1$, $C_2=0$ and $C_3=-1$ be possible and lead to similar edge states connecting the gaps despite one trivial Chern number?

Based on the discussion by [Roy and Harper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1603.06944), I assume that such systems would exist and that their topological quantum numbers should not be classified as $\mathbb{Z}$, but rather as $\mathbb{Z}^{\times 2}=\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}$, since all separate instances of the $\mathbb{Z}$-quantum numbers $C_i$ are connected.

Further, how does the exponent of $\mathbb{Z}^{\times n}$ depend on the symmetries of the system. According to Roy and Harper, I would assume that $n=1$ if the system satisfies particle-hole or time-reversal symmetry, and that $n\in\mathbb{N}\backslash\{0\}$ for systems without those symmetries. In the latter case, $n$ would be the number of band gaps.

(This question is closely related to another question I have asked, but I am convinced that this new question is much more precise and also sufficiently different from my other question.)

Edit: I think that my assumptions are correct. Since the number of edge states connecting valence and conduction band is determined by the [summed Berry curvatures of the occupied bands](https://arxiv.org/pdf/cond-mat/0307337.pdf) and consequently the sum of their respective Chern numbers, a Chern number of zero seems to not rule out the possibility of edge states connecting it to another band with Chern number zero.

Edit 2: I found [a paper that actually describes a 3-band insulator](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1204.1697.pdf) like I did in the example!